# How to write a string starting with '=' to a cell using Spreadsheet::WriteExcel

Tags: perl, excel, spreadsheet

I'm using the Perl package [Spreadsheet::WriteExcel](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Spreadsheet%3a%3aWriteExcel) to write an Excel file. I want to write a string that starts with the equal sign, "=ABC()", to a cell.

```
 $ws->write('A1', '=ABC()');
```

But I got an error message of

```
 Unknown function ABC() in formula
```

Can someone advise?

Comment: Note I do not want the cell to be interpreted (by the module, anyway) as a function. So yes, ABC is not a function and no, I'm not using it as an example, that's the actual string I want to put in the cell.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the `write_string` method directly instead of using `write`:

```
$ws->write_string('A1', '=ABC()');
```

[Spreadsheet::WriteExcel's](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Spreadsheet%3a%3aWriteExcel) `write` method is a convenience method that guesses what kind of data you're trying to store.  If it guesses wrong, you should use one of the type-specific methods.

Comment: I am the author of Spreadsheet::WriteExcel and this is the correct answer. See the documentation on the write() method for a detailed explanation.

Comment: and what if we want to write in excel using **write_row()** method which has arrayref as input, and arrayref is having something like this ("data","=") then also it throws error, is there any other solution for the same?

Answer (score 0):

@Cjm already provided the best answer. Still, I'd like to remember that's possible also to format any cell as *text* and type whatever you want, that won't be interpreted.